# how to handle wso2 accountLock,accountDisabled event

Tags: wso2, account, wso2-identity-server

I want to handle **accountLock(Unlock),accountDisabled** events and send it to my rest endpoint so i can refresh my local database users information. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When claims are getting updated (accountLocked, accountDisabled claims), WSO2 IS will trigger POST_SET_USER_CLAIMS event. Refer this [blog](https://medium.com/@isurakarunaratne/wso2-identity-server-eventing-framework-32505bcc1600) to know about eventing framework. When the account is getting locked/unlocked and disabled/enabled, this POST_SET_CLAIMS event will be triggered (This is fired after a claim update happens). You can [write custom event handlers](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/writing-a-custom-event-handler/#configuring-the-event-handler) to handlers to handle POST_SET_USER_CLAIMS event.

Already several IS components are listening to this accountLock and disable events. You can refer them, write a custom event handler and deploy into IS.  By writing a custom listener, You can listen to that event and add your own logic there.

[AccountLockHandler](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-event-handler-account-lock/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/handler/event/account/lock/AccountLockHandler.java)
[OAuthEventHandler](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth/listener/IdentityOauthEventHandler.java)

Comment: Are there another ways of connecting/synchronizing data in **wso2** and my **local** database?